# Java - Verify if a key from an hashmap exist in the other hashmap

Tags: java

How can I verify if a key from a hashmap exist in other hashmap.

I've two hashmaps

```
tablePlayer: <"Kim":"1" , "Bot":"2" , "Tim":"3">
tempPlayerList: <"Kim":"4" , "Bob":"1">
```

And my idea was to use `tempPlayerList` keys to find if there any key with the same value, e.g., Kim should be **true** and Bob should be **false**

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? You could iterate over `tablePlayer#keySet` to find the ones which make `templatePlayerList#containsKey` return `true` for instance. Many implementations possible :)

Answer (score 1):

I dont realy understand what you want but you can do :

```
for(String playerName : tablePlayer.keySet()){
    if(tempPlayerList.containsKey(playerName)){
        //hasmap contain name
    }else{
        //hasmap do not contain name
    }
}
```

Comment: I try this solution but it still doesn't get the if part only the else (using Kim;4)

`for(String playerName : tempPlayerList.keySet()){
     if(tablePlayer.containsKey(playerName)){
      System.out.println ("true");
     }
     else { 
      System.out.println ("false");
     }
    }`